# R row summing to a new column

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis

I'm new to R and this is probablly a very simple question.
I just haven't been able to make rsum/apply work

My task is to add all the different expense categories in my dataframe and create a new variable with this value like this:

(not the original)

```
Food      Dress    Car
235       564      532
452       632      719 
...       ...      ...
```

and then

```
Food      Dress    Car     Total
235       564      532     1331
452       632      719     1803
...       ...      ...     ...
```

I have tried:

rowsum, apply and aggregate and can't get it right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `addmargins` after converting to `matrix`

```
 addmargins(as.matrix(df1),2)
#     Food Dress Car  Sum
#[1,]  235   564 532 1331
#[2,]  452   632 719 1803
```

Or use `rowSums`

```
df1$Total <- rowSums(df1)
```

Or with `Reduce`

```
df1$Total <-  Reduce(`+`, df1)
```

Answer (score 2):

With `apply` functions:

```
cbind(dat, Total = apply(dat, 1, sum))
  Food Dress Car Total
1  235   564 532  1331
2  452   632 719  1803
```

or with just a:

```
 cbind(dat, Total = rowSums(dat))
  Food Dress Car Total
1  235   564 532  1331
2  452   632 719  1803
```